# Why does puppet module generate produce a Gemfile, and what is its purpose?

Tags: puppet, gem

I recently ran `puppet module generate`, and ended up with a whole lot of crap that looked unnecessary for a simple module. I mean, a lot of minimal modules  amount to templating  a configuration file or two and letting an open source Puppet module do the heavy lifting.

Puppet's documentation explained most of `puppet module generate` here:

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/modules_fundamentals.html

However, I didn't see anything in there about the Gemfile.

Of what use is the `Gemfile` generated by `puppet module generate`?

```
$ puppet module generate nathan-myapp_consul
$ cd myapp_consul/
$ ls
Gemfile     README.md   Rakefile    examples    manifests   metadata.json   spec
```

Here are the contents of this file:

```
source ENV['GEM_SOURCE'] || 'https://rubygems.org'

puppetversion = ENV.key?('PUPPET_VERSION') ? ENV['PUPPET_VERSION'] : ['>= 3.3']
gem 'metadata-json-lint'
gem 'puppet', puppetversion
gem 'puppetlabs_spec_helper', '>= 1.0.0'
gem 'puppet-lint', '>= 1.0.0'
gem 'facter', '>= 1.7.0'
gem 'rspec-puppet'

# rspec must be v2 for ruby 1.8.7
if RUBY_VERSION >= '1.8.7' && RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
  gem 'rspec', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'rake', '~> 10.0'
else
  # rubocop requires ruby >= 1.9
  gem 'rubocop'
end
```

`Gemfile` produced by `puppet module generate`, what is the point of you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Gemfile` is used by Ruby's [Bundler](https://bundler.io/) app to install RubyGems (Ruby libraries) used by the project - in this case, gems that can be used to *develop* the module. It's not used when installing or using the module within Puppet.

If you have Ruby installed, you can install these gems by running:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install  # or add `--path vendor` to install within the directory
```

A quick run-down of the purpose of these gems, and why you might find them useful:

- `metadata-json-lint` verifies the `metadata.json` file is correct, otherwise Puppet may not load the module and you couldn't upload it to the [Forge](https://forge.puppet.com)
- `puppetlabs_spec_helper` is a helper for running tests etc.
- `puppet-lint` validates your Puppet manifests against the Puppet [style guide](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/style_guide.html) ([more info](http://puppet-lint.com/))
- `rspec-puppet`, `rspec` let you write tests for Puppet classes, defined types etc to check that they compile without errors and create the right resources with the correct parameters ([more info](http://rspec-puppet.com/))
- `rake` is used to run preconfigured tasks from `Rakefile`, i.e. `rake test` will run all of the above and also validates manifests, ERB files etc.
- `rubocop` validates your Ruby code against a Ruby style guide, the equivalent to puppet-lint

As you suggest, these aren't necessary for a *minimal* module, but they are useful. You don't need to write tests or even lint your code, but using the tools may help you create a more reliable module and help you make changes without the risk of it not working within Puppet.

Comment: // , Would you say that it's roughly analogous to a `requirements/dev.txt` file as used in the examples presented as a response to Charles R's question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20720019/2146138?

Comment: Yes, it's very similar.